# Why I am getting too many open files error?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsurlsession

I am trying to download around 1100ea 32x32 .png icons from an API using Swift 4 decodable JSON method and trying to put then into a UIImage array.

However, after 208 I am getting error "Too Many Open Files".

So how can I download the rest of the icons and get rid of this error?

Here is how the error displaying:

> 2017-10-20 14:06:34.073515+0300 myProject[2205:286014] [] libsystem_network.dylib: nw_route_get_ifindex :: socket(PF_ROUTE, SOCK_RAW, PF_ROUTE) failed: [24] Too many open files

Here is code:

```
func getImageFromWeb(_ urlString: String, closure: @escaping (UIImage?) -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return closure(nil)
    }

    let task = URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error: \(String(describing: error))")
            return closure(nil)
        }
        guard response != nil else {
            print("no response")
            return closure(nil)
        }
        guard data != nil else {
            print("no data")
            return closure(nil)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            closure(UIImage(data: data!))
        }
    }; task.resume()
}

func downloadItemImages(){
    // Loop through items to get their relative logos
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: items.count, by: 1) {

        // Getting item logos (.png) and adding into image array
        let imageUrl = "https://files.test/img/items/32x32/\(items[i].id!).png"

        getImageFromWeb(imageUrl) { (image) in
            if let image = image {
                imgItems.append(image)
            }
        }
    }
    print("Total image putted into image array: \(imgItems.count)")
}
```

Comment: "My code is wrong, what can I do?" Well, first step would be to *show* us what you actually did... a [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: Do you close those files as soon as you can?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the responses. Unfortunately, I don't know how to close those files? I thought after saving them in the array would work.

Comment: I have added my code for you to review. Hope this will help to clarify the issue. I appreciate your time.